# NumberAnimation does not take into account property change until stopped

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a QML application with 2 rectangles: a large rectangle and a small rectangle inside the large one.

The small rectangle is animated and moves inside the large rectangle.

The animation is done by combining 2 NumberAnimation in a SequentialAnimation.

It works well, except that the `to` property of one of the NumberAnimation can change.
I would except the change of value to be applied immediately.
However, it is not taken into account until the animations are fully stopped and restarted.

Calling stop()/start() or restart() does not do anything.
I need to wait for the animation to actually finish and then start it again.

This can be demonstrated with the following QML code:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    RowLayout {
        Rectangle {
            id: topRect
            width: 400
            height: 400

            border {
                color: "red"
                width: 2
            }


            Rectangle {
                id: animatedRectangle
                width: 100
                height:100
                color: "blue"
            }
            SequentialAnimation{
                id: animation

                loops: Animation.Infinite
                running: cbAnimate.checked
                alwaysRunToEnd: true

                NumberAnimation {
                    id: forwardAnimation
                    target: animatedRectangle
                    property: "x"
                    to: sbWidth.value
                    duration: 2000
                }
                NumberAnimation {
                    id: backwardAnimation
                    target: animatedRectangle
                    property: "x"
                    to: 0
                    duration: 2000
                }
            }
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            CheckBox {
                id: cbAnimate
                text: "Animate"
            }
            SpinBox {
                id: sbWidth
                value: 300
                to: 400
            }
            SpinBox {
                value: forwardAnimation.to
                to: 999
            }
        }
    }

}
```

1. Start the animation with the checkbox
2. Change the value of `to` with `sbWidth`
3. See in the other SpinBox that the value of `to` was changed
4. Observe that the animation is still using the old value
5. Stop the animation, wait for the Rectangle to stop moving, Start the animation
6. Observe that the animation is using the value set in step 2

Isn't there a way to make the animation use the new value of to immediately?

This behavior is particularly painful when a QML element is animated by default and the `to` value depends on the geometry of Items, as during the creation of the QML scene Qt will create and then resize Items. Meaning that animation started at creation time won't get their values updated during the resize.

Comment: Check out this [post](https://www.qt.io/blog/new-in-qt-6.4-frameanimation-element); there are plenty of tricks and things you can do, such as using `Behavior` or a `Timer`. Other issue I'm not clear about is what happens if the value is on its way back to zero. The proxy method would raise the current value depending on the `sbWidth.value`, which I'm not sure if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

In this particular case the best solution is to use the workaround suggedted by @stephen-quan: animate a proxy property `property real animatedX` between `0.0` and `1.0`. And then bind the property I want to animate to this animated property and do the extra computation in this binding: `x: animatedX * sbWidth.value`. Eliminating the need of changing the `to` property of the animation.

### Details

The issue of animations not taking property change into account until restarted is a very old issue. It has been reported numerous times:

- [PropertyAnimation ignores from/to changes](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38932)
- [Changing an Animation
  duration has no effect](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61282)

Since Qt 6.4, the state has slightly improved. Quoting Qt documentation:

> Since Qt 6.4, it is possible to set the from, to, duration, and easing properties on a top-level animation while it is running. The animation will take the changes into account on the next loop.

However, it still does not affect the current loop and requires the animation to be top-level. So even with this improvement, I still need to animate a proxy property, ensuring changes are taken into account in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

I made various changes to your sample.

I introduced `from: 0` to your first `NumberAnimation`. This ensures that whenever you stop/start the animation, it will reset. Also, removing `alwaysRunToEnd` helps with that.

I introduced a new `property double val: 0` property which will range from 0.0 to 1.0. This is what I used `NumberAnimation` on instead of `x`. The advantage is, we know that the `NumberAnimation` will happily move from 0.0 to 1.0 and back to 0.0 consistently.

Then, I introduced a formula linking `val` to `x` and takes into account of `sbWidth.value`.

To make it easier to change `sbWidth.value` I changed it from a `SpinBox` to a `Slider`.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    RowLayout {
        Rectangle {
            id: topRect
            width: 400
            height: 400

            border {
                color: "red"
                width: 2
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: animatedRectangle
                property double val: 0.0
                x: val * sbWidth.value
                width: 100
                height:100
                color: "blue"
                Label {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: parent.x.toFixed(2)
                    color: "white"
                }
            }

            SequentialAnimation{
                id: animation

                loops: Animation.Infinite
                running: cbAnimate.checked
                //alwaysRunToEnd: true

                NumberAnimation {
                    id: forwardAnimation
                    target: animatedRectangle
                    property: "val"
                    from: 0
                    to: 1.0
                    duration: 2000
                }
                NumberAnimation {
                    id: backwardAnimation
                    target: animatedRectangle
                    property: "val"
                    to: 0
                    duration: 2000
                }
            }
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            CheckBox {
                id: cbAnimate
                text: "Animate"
            }
            Slider {
                id: sbWidth
                value: 300
                from: 100
                to: 400
            }
            Text {
                text: sbWidth.value.toFixed(2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: The omission of `from: 0` and setting `alwaysRunToEnd: true` are on purpose.